# jQuery script on a page with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html

On my page I have articles with dynamic content.

And I use two jQuery scripts to filter them

```
//Load more // less
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#article-list article:gt(10)').hide();
  $('#loadMore').click(function () {
  $('#article-list article:hidden:lt(2)').show();
      });
    });
    //hide articles with no image
  $('.myClass').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('src') === ""){
          $(this).closest('article').hide();
       }
    });
```

On the first load it's okay I see 10 articles all with images.

But when I click load more it loads 2 more articles but I see articles with no image.

How can I combine those two codes so when I click load more to hide the articles with no image

Comment: src attribute may not exists

Comment: it exists, if i remove  the load more script it it will hide the articles without image.

Comment: Had you indented your code, you would have seen that the last piece of code with the each loop, is outside the DOM ready handler. Is this code in the head, if so you have to place the loop inside the DOM ready handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the articles without images a class and filter on that

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#article-list article:gt(10)').hide();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
      $('#article-list article:not(.noimg):hidden:lt(2)').show();
    });
  //hide articles with no image
    $('.myClass').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('src') === ""){
        $(this).closest('article').addClass('noimg').hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You know you'll need to reuse it, so write a function:

```
function hideArticlesWithNoImages(){ 
   $('.myClass').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('src') === undefined || $(this).attr('src') === ''){
         $(this).closest('article').hide();
      }
   });
}
```

Then reference it:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#article-list article:gt(10)').hide();
   $('#loadMore').click(function () {
      $('#article-list article:hidden:lt(2)').show();
      hideArticlesWithNoImages();
    });
   hideArticlesWithNoImages();
});
```